# Tcpdump with pipeline goes slow

Tags: unix, buffer, pipeline, tcpdump

I'm very surprised by the behavior of tcpdump. I wrote simple code to do echoes like:

> > while (n)
> >
> > {
> >
> > n = fread(buf, 16, 1, stdin);
> >
> > printf("%s", buf);
> >
> > fflush(stdout);
> >
> > }

and then i do something like

> > $ tcpdump | ./EchoTest

i get a lot of tcpdump packets in echo output suppressed until some amount of them. Why it happens??
things like

> > $ cat file | ./EchoTest

or

> > $ tail -f file | ./EchoTest
> >
> > (with "$ echo "blabla" >> file)

works perfectly and i get output instantly. Does somebody know how to force tcpdump do its output in pipeline as it appeares??

Answer (score 2):

From the [`tcpdump` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump):

> **-l**
>
> Make stdout line buffered. Useful if you want to see the data while capturing it. E.g.,
>
> ''tcpdump -l | tee dat'' or ''tcpdump -l > dat & tail -f dat''.

Bottom line: the output of `tcpdump` is buffered - you need the `-l` option to have it output each packet/line immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Probably tcpdump has much more traffic to handle than your packets only, and what normally slows it down as well as @thkala's suggestion is resolving. Feeding it with `-n` option speeds up its output.

```
-n     Don't convert addresses (i.e., host addresses, port numbers, etc.) to names.
```